# A basic objective-C code from tutorial can not run

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I'm totally new to this language, please pardon me for this trivial question.

I was following a tut which the provide the following code:

[image: a screen shot of error code]

I guess that looking at the screen shot you know what issue I'm encountering with ?

Comment: Magically I rewrite the code by HAND, it works without error, I guess there could be hidden characters that come with code when I copy it from multiple pdf pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code. Magically I rewrite the code by HAND, it works without error, I guess there could be hidden characters that come with code when I copy it from multiple pdf pages.

Answer (score 3):

The above code works fine, *there is no problem surrounding your return statements with parenthesis*. I just ran the exact same code and it worked fine and gave the expected result.

```
NSString *boolString(BOOL yesNo) {
    if (yesNo == YES) {
        return (@"YES");
    } else {
        return (@"NO");
    }
}
```

Try cleaning your project (<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and build it again and see if that works. If it doesn't, open the Organizer from Xcode (<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) and delete the "Derived data" for your project and try to build it again.

---

Also, If you are trying to learn Objective-C, consider using Objective-C methods instead of C functions. (you call the following code like this: `[self boolString:YES];`)

```
- (NSString *)boolString:(BOOL)yesNo {
    if (yesNo == YES) {
        return (@"YES");
    } else {
        return (@"NO");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While this turned out to have nothing to do with the problem, it is still useful to understand the syntax for an instance method definition on objective-C:

```
- (NSString*) boolString: (BOOL yesno) {
    // code
    return @"objective-C string";
}
```

Comment: This is _still_ incorrect; it is absolutely possible to write a function that returns an object.

Answer (score 1):

change return statement, use -

```
return @"YES";
```

and

```
return @"NO";
```

Comment: this is not proper objective-C code. You are returning a C-string, not an NSString, and the closing `;` is missing! PS: I didn't down vote!

Comment: @thundersteele - that was just a typo :)

Comment: what confuses me more now is that the `()` brackets don't seem to cause a problem in return statements.

Comment: changed the code as your suggestion, error is displaying, it says "expected expression", here the screenshot https://skitch.com/runrunforest/83sad/screen-shot-2012-05-12-at-2.35.45-pm